# Insert max numeric value in Postgres column

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

Suppose I have a table like

```
CREATE TABLE public.products
(
    id       INTEGER NOT NULL
    article  CHARACTER VARYING(255)
    name     CHARACTER VARYING(255)
    quantity NUMERIC(10, 3)
)
```

As you can see, max value that can be inserted into `quantity` field is `9999999`. If I try to insert value like `9999999+1`, of course I receive

> Numeric value out of range: 7 ERROR:  numeric field overflow

Is there any way to track on `INSERT`/`UPDATE` that value of `quantity` exceeds `9999999` and instead of this value `insert`/`update` column with `9999999`?

Of course `NUMERIC(10, 3)` can be `NUMERIC(10, 2)` or `NUMERIC(5, 2)` and whatever, so the maximum value should **not be hardcoded** in query text.

In pseudocode it is something like

```
UPDATE table SET quantity = IF value > 9999999 THEN 9999999 ELSE value;
```

Sure, I can perform some data checks **before** running pgsql-query, but currently this is the last solution that I can use.

Comment: Similar question on SO. https://stackoverflow.com/q/36870972/3270427

Comment: This can be okay, but I don't know how to get the max value of current numeric field. With what should I compare my values in trigger.